# Multi product in one repo azure pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines

Like the tittle said, we use azure and have a repo with multiple product in it. We would like to run a test pipeline on every pull request and I was wondering if there was a way to determine a product automatically?

Or I setup that we could create to easily determine the products affected by changes?

The only thing that I came up was to specify folder path in the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

> We would like to run a test pipeline on every pull request and I was wondering if there was a way to determine a product automatically?

If you have multiple products in one repo and don't use different branches to differentiate, then using specify folder path will be the right way.

You could add the test pipeline on the target branch with folder path in the trigger:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    - releases/*
  paths:
    include:
    - docs
    exclude:
    - docs/README.md
```

Comment: Unfortunately the project is old and was never separated.
But if I understand properly, I would need 1 pipeline per product.